# Error while generating triplets in custom train loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, facenet

I'm building a face recognition model (FaceNet), for that as you may know we have to generate triplets, I'm getting error in my implementation, if any changes in below code or a better implementation please answer.

The below is the code for generating triplets for FaceNet model

```py
# since we have very less data we don't use the constraints given in the original paper
def select_all_triplets(images, labels):
    batch_size = len(labels)
    pos_images = [] # stores positive images
    neg_images = [] # stores negative images
    
    for i in range(batch_size):
        anchor_label = labels[i]
        
        pos_list = [] # stores indices of pos images
        neg_list = [] # stores indices of neg images
        
        for j in range(batch_size):
            if j != i: # ∴ len(pos_list) + len(neg_list) = len(images) - 1
                if labels[j] == anchor_label:
                    pos_list.append(j)
                else:
                    neg_list.append(j)
                    
        pos_images.append(tf.gather(images, pos_list))
        neg_images.append(tf.gather(images, neg_list))
        print(pos_list, neg_list)
        
    positive_images = tf.random.shuffle(tf.stack(pos_images))
    negative_images = tf.random.shuffle(tf.stack(neg_images))
    
    return positive_images, negative_images

#testing
img, lbl = next(iter(train_ds))
select_all_triplets(img, lbl)
```

but getting error as

```py
InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [7,96,96,3] != values[2].shape = [6,96,96,3] [Op:Pack] name: stack
```

so thought of using ragged tensor but not getting how. If there are other approaches for the code please list it

Comment: which line is making the error?

Comment: Can you give more context on your question, @VVY? It's easier to get help when there is enough context. Feel free to review the best practices on that :)

Comment: getting error while stacking

Comment: @HSL I've edited the question, please check it and answer

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the issue of the inconsistent shapes, maybe you could use [RaggedTensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor) specifically [`tf.ragged.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ragged/stack) to store the variable-length lists of positive and negative images before using [`tf.random.shuffle`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/shuffle):

```
def shuffle_inner_values(ragged_tensor):
    return tf.ragged.map_flat_values(
        lambda t: tf.random.shuffle(t),
        ragged_tensor
    )

def select_all_triplets(images, labels):
    batch_size = len(labels)
    pos_images = [] # stores positive images
    neg_images = [] # stores negative images
    
    for i in range(batch_size):
        anchor_label = labels[i]
        
        pos_list = [] # stores indices of pos images
        neg_list = [] # stores indices of neg images
        
        for j in range(batch_size):
            if j != i: # ∴ len(pos_list) + len(neg_list) = len(images) - 1
                if labels[j] == anchor_label:
                    pos_list.append(j)
                else:
                    neg_list.append(j)
                    
        pos_images.append(tf.gather(images, pos_list))
        neg_images.append(tf.gather(images, neg_list))
        
    positive_images = tf.ragged.stack(pos_images)
    negative_images = tf.ragged.stack(neg_images)
    
    # Shuffle ragged tensors along their inner dimensions
    positive_images = shuffle_inner_values(positive_images)
    negative_images = shuffle_inner_values(negative_images)

    return positive_images, negative_images

#testing
img, lbl = next(iter(train_ds))
pos_images, neg_images = select_all_triplets(img, lbl)
print(pos_images, neg_images)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'RaggedTensor' object has no attribute 'map_inner_values'
`

Comment: Try using `map_flat_values`